# Clonando elemento modificado com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Em uma tabela HTML de referência, a tag `<tfoot>` é acessada e tem seus dados modificados [não incluso aqui por estar funcionando], e ao usar o método [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) do jQuery para criar um *deep copy* para a tabela de clone, o conteúdo de `<tfoot>` é clonado corretamente mas o valor que foi modificado na tabela de referência não é enviado para a tabela de clone, o que é clonado são os dados iniciais estáticos por default, como clonar o que também está modificado no `DOM` da tabela de referência para a tabela de clone, o que está faltando?

O jQuery me auxiliou na construção da função abaixo e funciona, mas como mencionei, não cria o deep copy com o `DOM` modificado.

```
<table class="ref">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Conteúdo default</th>
    <tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="clone">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
$('table.ref input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
    let $cloningFoot = $('table.ref tfoot tr').clone();
    $('table.clone tfoot').html($cloningFoot);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo código que postou, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo, a clonagem funciona. O que faltou aí é que depois que faz o clone vc deveria pegar o seu conteúdo com o método **`html()`**. Repare que eu altero o conteúdo do `footer` da tabela **ref** e este conteúdo novo é clonado para o footer na tabela **clone** normalmente:

```js
$('table.ref input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $('table.ref tfoot tr th').text('Outro Conteúdo !!!');  //novo conteúdo
  let $cloningFoot = $('table.ref tfoot').clone();
  $('table.clone tfoot').html($cloningFoot.html()); //pega o conteúdo e insere
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="ref">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Conteúdo default</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="clone">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Neste exemplo é mostrado no console que a clonagem funciona:

```js
$('table.ref input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $('table.ref tfoot tr th').text('Outro Conteúdo !!!');
  let $cloningFoot = $('table.ref tfoot').clone();
  $('table.clone tfoot').html($cloningFoot.html());

  console.log('Tabela ref: ', $('table.ref').html());
  console.log('Tabela clone: ', $('table.clone').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="ref">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Conteúdo default</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="clone">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```